# Show the particular type data to table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an list of array values. And each object having an `type` key values. So in my table view i should not show the particular type object.And all other object i needs to show. How can i do that?.

Here my values :

```
(

        {
        "booking_id" = 1137;
        "category_id" = 6;
        "category_name" = Public;
        type = Public;

    },


        {
        "booking_id" = 1179;
        "category_id" = 1;
        "category_name" = bay range;   
        type = Offerers;

    },
        {
        "booking_id" = 1178;
        "category_id" = 1;
        "category_name" = newYork range;
        type = Offerers;

    },
        {
        "booking_id" = 1137;
        "category_id" = 6;
        "category_name" = Public range;
        type = Public;

    }
)
```

Like above. In my table view from the above values. I should not show the `type == "public`". So all other values i needs to show in table view. How can i do that.

I tried with checking the type == "public". But not sure how can i proceed from there.

Any solutions would be helpful.

Thanks.

**Updated :**  I have tried below code too. But it dint work.

```
 var detailsarr = NSMutableArray()

var dic = self.detailsarr.object(at: indexPath.section) as! NSArray;
```

i am doing like :

```
dic = dic.filter { $0["type"] != "Public" }
```

Comment: What do your table view & data source delegate look like? You supply data for the table to display from the data source, so your decision logic goes there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  no, i said. i tried some thing. But its not working

Comment: `NS(Mutable)Array` is horrible. You are fighting the strong type system. And this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need the feature not to display the data of type = public

start with enum ,

`enum TypeData {
   case public
   case offerers
}`

define your model

```
struct ModelData : Codable {
 var booking_id, category_id : Int
 var category_name : String
 var type : TypeDta
}
```

then in tableviewcontroller

`var rootData : [ModelData] {
  didSet {tableViewDataSource = rootData.filter{$0.type != .public}} 
}`

This will the data source for numberOfRows and cellForRowAt

```
var tableViewDataSource : [ModelData] = []()
```

Then call `tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this array for the table data source

```
var arr = [Item]()
```

Then do

```
arr = arr.filter { $0.type != "Public" }
```

where

```
struct Item {
    let booking_id,category_id:Int
    let category_name,type:String
}
```

For a dictionary

```
 var arr = [[String:Any]]()

 arr = arr.filter { $0["type"] != "Public" }
```

Comment: `arr = arr.filter { $0.type != "Public" }`. Measn my arr will contain except "Public" object. ??

Comment: i added like this `let values = dic.filter { ($0 as AnyObject).type != "Public" }` it was force to chnage like this  or like this `dic = dic.filter { ($0 as AnyObject).type != "Public" } as NSArray`

Comment: type is not string its like `type = Public;`. I am not using model class for that. How can i handle that ?

Comment: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: arr in my case was `as! NSArray` not `[[String:Any]]()`

Comment: do `as! [[String:Any]]`

Comment: i can't do with `[[String:Any]] ` bec all the code is done every wr as like my updated post only..if it change that.Then it would be an major chnage

Comment: it deserves to make it a model  but if you have to `arr.filter { ($0 as AnyObject)["type"] as! String != "Public" } as NSArray` but not recommended

Comment: i tried like `var Cdic = self.detailsarr.object(at: indexPath.section) as! NSArray
           Cdic = Cdic.filter { ($0 as AnyObject)["type"] as! String != "Public" } as! NSArray
            print(Cdic)
            let type = (Cdic.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category_name") as? String`

Comment: But getting crash in my `let type` line `Thread 1: Fatal error: Array index out of range`. when i check `Cdic` in console i can get the 3 object values. But getting that crash